# What is this particle effect?

Tags: guild-wars-2

So my warrior seems to have a strange gold flakes particle effect on her and I'm not sure where it came from. It doesn't seem to be related to anything, such as adrenaline.

Comment: I think she's drunk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that this effect is applied to your character when you equip '[Signet of Rage](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Signet_of_Rage)'. The elite signet.

Comment: She gets so full of rage that gold flakes float up from her!

Comment: I need to get enraged more often in real life then!